# Looking up nearest point of interest using MapKit

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit

How can I look up the nearest point of interest and its category as plain text without querying for any specific location category?

```
        let request = MKLocalSearch.Request()
        request.pointOfInterestFilter = .includingAll
        //request.naturalLanguageQuery = "Supermarket"
        request.region = mapView.region
```

The problem is that as soon as I am omitting the query portion the search is not executed and I only get a `MKErrorDomain error 4`.

How can I get the nearest point of interest for my current location without narrowing search results?

Answer (score 0):

Use a `MKLocalPointsOfInterestRequest` instead of `MKLocalSearch.Request()`.

Apples Documentation: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mklocalpointsofinterestrequest

It is basically the same as `MKLocalSearch.Request()` but without the `.naturalLanguageQuery`.

**Answer 2**

Since you want "everything" you might also have a look at `MKMapFeatureAnnotation`: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mkmapfeatureannotation?language=_2

It allows you to tap on and use the small annotations provided by Apple on the map. In that case you don't have to search at all, it's already there.

Explained here https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2022/10035/

This feature requires iOS 16